# Free sources of mapping data for France

Tags: data, mapping, france

We are moving to France soon, and are currently investigating a lot of areas.  Does anyone know of good online/offline resources for French mapping?  I am very interested in mapping, weather, environmental, geological, hydrological data, as we are preparing to create a zero emissions home out there and want to get the best area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You have some environnemntal data [there](http://inpn.mnhn.fr/telechargement/cartes-et-information-geographique), provided by le *Muséum National d'Histoire Naturel*.
- The [data.gouv.fr](http://www.data.gouv.fr/) portal just opened few days ago.
- IGN geoportal : http://www.geoportail.fr/
- Some data from IGN are available [for free](http://professionnels.ign.fr/45/licences/pour-les-donnees-gratuites.htm).
- You will find many ressources regarding hydrology on [that document](http://sierm.eaurmc.fr/faq/documents/IDD_Recap_Externe.pdf) (pdf) - see also http://www.eaufrance.fr.
- Regarding geology, [BRGM](http://www.brgm.fr/cartegeol.jsp) will be the provider you are looking for

At the local scale, you will also get some more data :

- http://opendata.paris.fr/
- http://opendata.montpelliernumerique.fr/
- http://www.opendata71.fr/
- http://www.data.rennes-metropole.fr/

Comment: and of course http://www.geoportail.fr/ !

Comment: @julien : indeed, I missed that ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in weather station data for [France](http://worldweather.wmo.int/062/m062.htm).
There is also great historical trend data on [WeatherSpark](http://weatherspark.com/#!dashboard;q=Paris,+France).

[image]

Comment: Keep it coming, all great stuff cheers!  Didn't realsie how much was there!

Comment: This is currently my favourite new web page!  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

[French Flood maps](http://cartorisque.prim.net/telechargement/telechargement.html) in MapInfo .Tab form.

Answer (score 1):

**French level or local**

- For sea, [IFREMER data](http://www.ifremer.fr/sextant/)
- Sea coasts [orthophotos](http://www.geolittoral.equipement.gouv.fr/)
- About [Risks](http://cartorisque.prim.net/)
- Lots of data too on every DREAL (local representant of ministery of environment for each regions). No compile data, need to visit every sites. [List here](http://www.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/Liste-des-21-DREAL.html)
- [Corine Land Cover](http://sd1878-2.sivit.org) Data (french equivalent of EU data from http://www.eea.europa.eu/)
- [List of french datacatalogs](http://datacatalogs.org/dataset?groups=france&q=france) (like a planet for blog but aggregate list of data portals)
- [Sandre data](http://sandre.eaufrance.fr/geonetwork/srv/fr/main.home) (about waters, like eaufrance)

**Datasets covering France but European or Worldwide**

- [ESA data](http://www.gmes.info/pages-secondaires/news/news-detail/?no_cache=1&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=631) (from landsat)
- [NASA datasets](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=%E2%9C%93&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle)
- Most french remote sensing data are not free, so US best provider for [weather](http://wwwghcc.msfc.nasa.gov/GOES/)
- Beautiful but not really for analysis, [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)

Comment: Cheers @ThomasG77 - I appreciate it all

Answer (score 0):

you may find more in one of these 3 archives:

3 Free GIS Data Portals: https://mangomap.com/blog/3-free-gis-data-portals/

(I know Wilson's, but perhaps the others may help you too)