# Looking for major river basins boundaries worldwide

Tags: data

I need the data (lat,long) for the world's major river basins boundaries. I want to use it in MATLAB, like "load coast" that gives the coast's boundary.

Comment: Have you tried looking?  A Google search for the *title of this question* found free shapefiles at the [Global Runoff Data Center](http://www.bafg.de/nn_267044/GRDC/EN/02__Services/02__DataProducts/MajorRiverBasins/riverbasins__node.html?__nnn=true): it's on the *very first page* returned by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Naturalearth offers a global "Rivers + lake centerlines" dataset:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on a [post on French data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/free-sources-of-mapping-data-for-france?newsletter=1&nlcode=38699%7C9545) you have a couple of sources for free data at these links:

- http://www.eaufrance.fr/
- http://sandre.eaufrance.fr/geonetwork/srv/fr/main.home

Comment: These appear to be France-only datasets.  Where on these sites are the *worldwide* data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer

Comment: The linked page only talks about oceans. Rivers aren't even mentioned ... Is it just the description that is misleading?