# Belgium Flood And Precipitation Mapping

Tags: maps, data, flood, precipitation, belgium

Similar to [Free sources of mapping data for France](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/free-sources-of-mapping-data-for-france), does any one know a source for free downloadable flood and precipitation maps for Belgium?

Answer (score 3):

The flood maps for the north of Belgium

http://www.integraalwaterbeleid.be/nl/beleidsinstrumenten/watertoets/overstromingsgevoelig2011.zip/view

Comment: Just a heads up: There's now also a 2014 version (which is the legally binding one). All versions can be found here: http://www.geopunt.be/download?container=overstromingsgevoelig&title=Overstromingsgevoelige%20gebieden%202014%20%28Watertoets%29

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above post, I'd like to point out there's several datasets. The one referered above holds the THEORETICAL floodable areas, which is used as far as determining the requirements for waterbuffers goes, there is however a dataset known as 'recent overstroomde gebieden':
http://www.agiv.be/gis/nieuws/?artid=1510

it lists all areas known to have flooded since 1988. Upon registry through the GIRAF application (the sales bit of AGIV) this data can be requested for free, in both SHP and GML formats.